# Android Download Manager filename with ':'

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using Download Manager in my app.

I have many files where some include many different symbols.

One particular symbol ":" is causing problems.

On Pixel phones or Samsung phones, while I can download other files I am not able to download files that contain this symbol.

On any other phone (One Plus for example) I am not experiencing this behavior and can easily download such files.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104980/downloadmanager-broadcasts-downloadmanager-error-file-error-when-app-is-installe) that this may be due to filesystem, but I am pretty sure that on any other apps I would be able to download files with colon in their names.

Comment: No it is a forbidden character.

Comment: @blackapps any idea why I can download these files on other phones?

Comment: This is not about download but about creating files/folders.

Comment: @blackapps is there any way to circumvent this? These characters seem only forbidden in creation. When I open or move existing files with a colon in the name, everything works fine.

Comment: It depends on Android version of used phone.

Comment: You can tell DownloadManager under wich file name to save the download. So replace forbidden chars first.